# How to align `TabBar` to the left with a custom starting position

Tags: dart, flutter, padding, tabbar

I'm currently working on a Flutter app in which I'd like to display the `TabBar` starting on the left. If an `AppBar` has a leading property I'd like to indent the starting position of the `TabBar` to match it. Then on the scroll, it would still pass through and not leave the white area.

This is the code that I have that currently displays a `TabBar` in the middle of the `AppBar`:

```
AppBar(
  bottom: TabBar(
    isScrollable: true,
    tabs: state.sortedStreets.keys.map(
      (String key) => Tab(
        text: key.toUpperCase(),
      ),
    ).toList(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I didn't quite get this, can you also share the screenshot for the same?

Answer (score 30):

The Flutter TabBar widget spaces out the tabs evenly when the scrollable property of TabBar is set to false, as per the comment in the [tabs.dart source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tabs.dart#L1053):

```
// Add the tap handler to each tab. If the tab bar is not scrollable
// then give all of the tabs equal flexibility so that they each occupy
// the same share of the tab bar's overall width.
```

So you can get a left-aligned TabBar by using:

```
isScrollable: true,
```

and if you want to use indicators that are the same width as the Tab labels (eg. as you would by if you set `indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label`) then you may also want to have a custom indicator set like so:

```
TabBar(
  indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    width: 4,
    color: Color(0xFF646464),
  ),
  insets: EdgeInsets.only(
    left: 0,
    right: 8,
    bottom: 4)),
  isScrollable: true,
  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),
  tabs: _tabs
    .map((label) => Padding(
      padding:
        const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
      child: Tab(text: "$label"),
   ))
   .toList(),
)
```

Example of what this will look like:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

You can use **Align** Widget to align the tabs of the **TabBar** to left, which will be the child of PreferredSize.

This worked for me:

```
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
    ///Note: Here I assigned 40 according to me. You can adjust this size acoording to your purpose.
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: state.sortedStreets.keys.map(
          (String key) => Tab(
              text: key.toUpperCase(),
          ),
        ).toList(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

In case you only need **TabBar** in body you can remove the **PreferredSize** Widget.

Comment: No, you can not remove the PreferredSize widget because only widgets that implement PreferredSizeWidget can be used as the app bar 'bottom' and 'Align' does not.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe your `TabBar` isn't filled up the whole horizontal area. What happen if you wrap the `TabBar` within another Container that expanded the whole width like this.

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity
  child: TabBar(
    ...
    ...
  )
)
```

Answer (score 9):

This is only fix it

```
isScrollable: true,
tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start
```

Answer (score 8):

To Align tabbar with same header bar height by default use constant **kToolbarHeight**

```
bottom: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
  child: Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  child: TabBar(/*your code*/),
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

To align tab bar perfect solution here:

```
   bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: TabBar(

                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                indicatorColor: AppColors.cyan_blue,
                labelColor: AppColors.cyan_blue,
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 4.0,
                      color: AppColors.cyan_blue,
                    ),
                insets: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 110.0)),
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                //For Selected tab
                unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                isScrollable: true,
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                tabs: [
                  Container(
                    child: Tab(
                      text: "Profile Summary\t\t\t",
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Tab(
                      text: "Business summary",
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

**This will help you `kToolbarHeight` and `Alignment.centerLeft`**

```
 bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            //alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart
            child: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: _tabs,
              controller: _tabController,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: use `alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart` for RTL start alignment (left for ltr, right for rtl)