# Flutter - Wrap tab indicator width with respect to tab text

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar

As I am new to flutter,
In Android,

```
app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
```

I use this property in tabbar to wrap the indicator size with respect to tab text.
May I know how to achieve in flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Figured out the answer,

```
TabBar( controller: _tabController,
                  indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                  tabs: getTabs(),
                )



indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label
```

this property **indicatorSize** solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the `isScrollable` to `true`

> If isScrollable is true, then each tab is as wide as needed for its label and the entire TabBar is scrollable. Otherwise each tab gets an equal share of the available space.

```
  bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true, // here

              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Car',),
                Tab(text: 'Transit Bus',),
                Tab(text: 'Bike',),
              ],
            ),
```

#### References

- [isScrollable property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/isScrollable.html)
- [Dart Pad Example](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)
- [Also see similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895566/4712391)

Comment: This changes the tab's width, and the indicator's width is still the tab's width and not the text's width. OP's answer is correct